# Finding the mean, given only the mean and sample size, normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, means

You draw a sample of size 30 from a normally distributed population with a standard deviation of four.

I am not sure if its just because we hadnt had any examples like this one, however I am struggling with how to find the distribution of the mean for this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that the sum of independent and identically distributed normal random variables i.e.
$$\bar{X} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$$
is also Normal
$$\bar{X} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{N})$$
where $N$ is the sample size and $\mu,\sigma^2$ are the true mean and variances. So plugging in values, we get that your samples mean is Normally distributed as follows
$$\bar{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{N}(\mu, \frac{4^2}{30})$$
So, the distribution of the mean is again a Normal distribution with mean equal to the true mean $\mu$ and variance equal to $\frac{4^2}{30}$.

Comment: Since the samples are initially drawn from a normal distribution, surely the Central Limit Theorem is overkill?

Comment: yeah you're right .. thanks for letting me know the samples are also normal

Comment: Thank you so much! For the life of me I couldnt find the correct formula for this.

Comment: Welcome @FeleciaMarinelli, if you found the answer useful, you could upvote the answer and mark it as correct so that others know it was useful :)